# Open a new tab as Pin Tab in browser on clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, browser

I've got many links in my web page. While redirecting to the link I want to open a new page in  browser's next tab. It is quiet natural but my question is: is there any possibility to open such redirected pages as pinned tabs (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open) in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You just can't tell the browser to pin a tab. That will be a bad security flaw. Only the user can choose to pin or unpin tabs. If you want to control the browser's behavior you have to do it by creating an extension.

Comment: @Suji any reason why my answer got unmarked as correct? Did you find any solution?